# converting number to bitfield string in bash

Tags: bash, shell, math, bit

What might be the most concise way in `bash` to convert a number into a bitfield character string like 1101?

In effect I am trying to do the opposite of

```
echo $[2#1101]
```

Why: I need to send a parameter to a program that takes bitfields in the form of a full string like "0011010110"  but often only need to enable one or few bits as in:

```
SUPPRESSbits=$[1<<16] runscript.sh  # OR
SUPPRESSbits=$[1<<3 + 1<<9] runscript.sh  # much more readable when I know what bits 3 and 9 toggle in the program
```

Then runscript.sh then sees in its env a `SUPPRESSbits=65536` rather than `SUPPRESSbits="1000000000000000"` and ends in parse error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy way:

```
$ dc <<<2o123p
1111011

$ bc <<<'obase=2; 123'
1111011
```

Comment: Great, it can hardly get more concise than with `dc` there. So `bash` doesn't seem to have number-to-string built in

Answer (score 1):

I doubt about bash but you always can use perl:

```
a=123; b=$(perl -e 'printf "%b", "'$a'"'); echo $b
1111011
```